# ¿Como hacer que mi programa intente reconexión cuando se va el internet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

```
import serial, serial.tools.list_ports, sys, time, json
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace

direccionIP=''
puertoConexion=''

# Variables globales para el envio de datos a traves del
# puerto serial
puertoPredefinido = ''
puertosSeriales = ''
arduino = ''

# Variables globales para la comunicacion con la app
# utilizando SocketIO
mensaje = ''
socketIO = ''

# Funcion ejecutada con cada actualizacion
# La variable msg recibe los datos provenientes del servidor
def enviar_a_Arduino(msg):
    # Recuperamos el objeto JSON que viene en la comunicacion
    argumentoJson = json.loads(msg)

    try:
        # Si el Arduino esta conectado, procesamos los datos y los enviamos
        if not mensaje == '{"STATUS":"ERROR","CODIGO":"ARDUINO NO CONECTADO"}':
            # Obtencion de cantidad de LEDs
            cantidadDeLEDS = 0
            for contador in argumentoJson['LEDS']:
                cantidadDeLEDS += 1

            # Formacion de la cadena de datos con el numero de LED y su color
            datosParaEnviar = str(cantidadDeLEDS)
            for contador in argumentoJson['LEDS']:
                datosParaEnviar += ','+str(contador['NUM'])+','+str(contador['RGB'])

            # Envio de datos
            global arduino
            arduino.write(datosParaEnviar.encode())
            time.sleep(1.5)

            # Envio de status al servidor
            global mensaje
            mensaje = '{"STATUS":"OK"}'
            global socketIO
            socketIO.emit('response', mensaje)

        #Si no esta conectado el Arduino, se procede a intentar conectarlo de nuevo
        else:
            try:
                # Enlistado de los puertos seriales disponibles
                global puertosSeriales
                puertosSeriales = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
                for puerto in puertosSeriales:
                    # Si el puerto contiene como identificaro la palabra Arduino,
                    # este es el puerto conectado al Arduino Mega
                    if "Arduino" in puerto[1]:
                        global puertoPredefinido
                        puertoPredefinido = puerto[0]
                # Se abre el puerto a 115200 baudios
                global arduino
                arduino = serial.Serial(puertoPredefinido, 115200)
                time.sleep(2)

                # Inicio del proceso de envio de datos
                cantidadDeLEDS = 0
                for contador in argumentoJson['LEDS']:
                    cantidadDeLEDS += 1
                    datosParaEnviar = str(cantidadDeLEDS)
                for contador in argumentoJson['LEDS']:
                    datosParaEnviar += ','+str(contador['NUM'])+','+str(contador['RGB'])

                global arduino
                arduino.write(datosParaEnviar.encode())
                time.sleep(1.5)

                global mensaje
                mensaje = '{"STATUS":"OK"}'
                global socketIO
                socketIO.emit('response', mensaje)

            except Exception:
                # Si el Arduino no fue encontrado conectado al PC, se envia el error
                global mensaje
                mensaje = '{"STATUS":"ERROR","CODIGO":"ARDUINO NO CONECTADO"}'
                global socketIO
                socketIO.emit('response', mensaje)

    except Exception:
        # Si el Arduino no fue encontrado conectado al PC, se envia el error
        global mensaje
        mensaje = '{"STATUS":"ERROR","CODIGO":"ARDUINO NO CONECTADO"}'
        global socketIO
        socketIO.emit('response', mensaje)

# Informacion del Socket
                       #Servidor y puerto
socketIO = SocketIO(direccionIP, int(puertoConexion))

# Primer intento de abrir el puerto serial conectado al
# Arduino cuando inicia el sistema
try:
    global puertosSeriales
    puertosSeriales = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for puerto in puertosSeriales:
        if "Arduino" in puerto[1]:
            global puertoPredefinido
            puertoPredefinido = puerto[0]

    global arduino
    arduino = serial.Serial(puertoPredefinido, 115200)
    time.sleep(2)

except Exception:
    global mensaje
    mensaje = '{"STATUS":"ERROR","CODIGO":"ARDUINO NO CONECTADO"}

socketIO.on('status', enviar_a_Arduino, '/32-BGO-1')# Metodo a ejecutar en caso de que se reciban datos bajo el evento "status" en el canal "/32-BGO-1"
socketIO.on('status', enviar_a_Arduino, '/32-BGR-1') #Metodo a ejecutar en caso de que se reciban datos bajo el  evento "status" en el canal "/32-BGR-1"

socketIO.wait() # Espera indefinida
```

El problema es que no funciona si creo un evento reconnect, viendo la documentación de la biblioteca, es escasa, pero mi función sería

```
def on_reconnect():
    socketIO.on('status', enviar_a_Arduino, '/32-BGO-1')
    socketIO.on('status', enviar_a_Arduino, '/32-BGR-1')
```

Comment: ¿Kuroi enlazas tu función con el evento: `socketIO.on('reconnect', on_reconnect)`?

Comment: No, lo que pasa es que la función socketIO.wait(), creo que espera a que mandes lo que necesites, ya que se traba en esa línea y si se me va el internet, tengo que volver a correr ese script.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, solo habia la necesidad de agregar un while infinito y en la función wait, agregarle un tiempo esfecifico de espera

```
While True:
    socketIO.on('status', enviar_a_Arduino, '/32-BGO-1')
    socketIO.on('status', enviar_a_Arduino, '/32-BGR-1')        
    socketIO.wait(seconds=1)
```